# piece of porcelain fell into cylinder,

Tags: chevrolet, cylinder-head, trailblazer

I have a 2003 chevy trailblazer, I was changing the coil packs and plugs and one of the plugs was broken and a piece of porcelain went into the cylinder. I thought that I got it all out,but I did not, any way put new plug and coil packs on,started car, and it idled very high and made a hard grinding sound then quit. What damage could it have done? can it be removed? can it be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is you can go to advance Auto parts and they have a small camera that fits inside of spark plug holes I would say remove the coil and spark plug and put that camera down there and look inside your cylinder and see if you either stamped the piston scratch the cylinder walls or hopefully did not stamp one of your valves inside the head that would be your best bet without taking the engine completely apart to see what happened but if the engine is running rough after your ordeal you might have a bent either push rod or valve